# Why use ` instead of " for strings

Tags: javascript, function

```
function callMe (name){    
    console.log(`Hello ${name} Welcome To Bangladesh`);      
}

callMe('Simanta');
```

I don't understand the 2nd line (`console.log()`) . Why use ` instead of ", and why should I use the curly brackets?

Comment: [JavaScript template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove ` and use ", and see what happens.

```
function callMe (name){

console.log("Hello ${name} Welcome To Bangladesh");

}

callMe('Simanta');
```

You would get `Hello ${name} Welcome To Bangladesh` logged to the console.

String literals (enclosed by " or ') do not allow embedded expresisons. So, `${name}` isn't resolved to its value, and the string `Hello ${name} Welcome To Bangladesh` is logged to the screen as it is.

Template literal (enclosed by `), on the other hand, allows embedded expressions. So, if `${name}` appears within back quotes (`), it is resolved to its value and you get the nice output `Hello Simanta Welcome To Bangladesh`.

The dollar sign followed by curly braces `${name}` appearing inside a template literal indicates expression, which is the part that needs to be evaluated